`Error: destinationAmountSwapped is zero` Raydium CurveCalculator
I am trying to get the swap results before making a swap using from Raydium V2 SDK
  const swapResult = CurveCalculator.swap(
    inputAmount,
    baseIn ? baseReserve : quoteReserve,
    baseIn ? quoteReserve : baseReserve,
    new BN(feeConfigs[0].tradeFeeRate)
  );

But it keeps failing with
Error: destinationAmountSwapped is zero


seems like my tokens balances are too low and are causing this error.
